# call method in controller when submit button clicked?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I'm quite sure this is possible but I can't find any info on it. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: Are you using servlets??

Comment: What MVC Framework are you using?

Comment: which MVC framework you are using?

Answer (score 4):

- Take a HTML form
- set action to someServlet
- take method = POST
- override `doPost()` and write your code there

**See**

- [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

A very sleek MVC example can be found [here](http://simple.souther.us/ar01s05.html). You can download it, read the source code yourself to understand and grasp the concept.